# How to find large/temp files in a volume

Tags: shell, rhel

How can I find what files are occupying more space when I execute the below command?

```
df -kh
```

it gives me the following :

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg0-root   32G  2.1G   29G   7% /
tmpfs                  32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             283M   34M  234M  13% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg0-home  2.9G  154M  2.6G   6% /home
/dev/mapper/vg0-opt   7.5G  205M  6.9G   3% /opt
/dev/mapper/vg0-tmp   7.5G   21M  7.1G   1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/vg0-var   5.8G 1016M  4.5G  19% /var
```

How can I find what is there in:

```
/dev/mapper/vg0-var
```

As I see that is constantly filling up everyday by at least 2MB.
Is there any way to navigate to that and check what is there in the filesystem?
Is there any way to find out the largest file under that mountpoint?

Comment: Something similar could give you a clue: `du -sch /var/*/** | awk '/[0-9]+G/'`

Comment: `ndcu` is generally a good way to track down large files in a filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted output shows that `/dev/mapper/vg0-var` is mounted on `/var`, so you could navigate to the root of that filesystem with

```
cd /var
```

To see how much space was used by each file and subdirectory (ignoring hidden files for the time), use

```
du -ks /var/*
```

It is most likely that routine log files in `/var/log/` account for most or all of the daily increase you have.  Many modern unix-like systems have some form of log rotation enabled, so that logs will accumulate for some period of time on a new system, but then usage will plateau as the maximum number of configured logs is reached and old ones are deleted approximately as fast as new ones are added.

Comment: Thanks, I found out that most of the files having large size in ' var ' are /var/cache and /var/lib/modules
what do they exactly mean and contain is it Ok to remove or compress some files out there

Comment: @Rebbeca Your partition is only 19% full. I don't see any reason to remove any files.  Measure usage over time to see areas of growth.

Comment: I know but in case it grows which surely it will , but not sure how much the log will take space for this , so is there any way to deal with this over time.
It will be great if you provide some insights on this.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the threshold (10) to taste, it simply suppresses uninteresting directories:

```
du -k /var | awk '$1 >= 10' | sort -n
```

Or view the top dozen directories: `du -k /var | sort -n | tail -12`

That gives directory sizes. The corresponding command for file sizes within a certain directory is:

```
ls -l . | sort -nk5
```